# Need help to understand the meaning of this formula 

Tags: multivariate-analysis, mean, covariance

I need help to understand the meaning of the following formula:
    $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i,j=1}^n(x_i-\mu_i)(x_j-\mu_j)c_{ij}$$

where C is positive semidefinite matrix, $\mu_i$ is the mean of $x_i$.

I was thinking, since $c_{ij}$ is the covariance between $x_i$ and $x_j$, this formula kind of sums up the correlation between all the pairs of $x_i$ and $x_j$. Does that make sense? Do you have any other interpretation of the formula?

Many thanks in advance,

**Edited v1**

Matrix $C$ is simply a positive semidefinite matrix, not necessarily covariance matrix. $\mu $ was given very general as well, not mentioned to be mean. That was my own interpretation of it. If you know of another formula using $\mu$ with different meaning, please do tell.

Many thanks for Emre and Nesp for the response. So far, it really makes sense.

**Edited v2**

Thank you all very much for your responses. The Mahalanobis distance is a very good explanation of the formula given. However, I wonder if we take off the diagonal (all the i=j elements) from the formula, does it still make any sense? Without the condition $i\neq j$, the summation can even be negative, right? In that case, the interpretation of distance seems to be not appropriate anymore. (I made the modification to the formula above)

Comment: Where did you get this formula from? I don't see much sense in it, frankly.

Comment: @StasK: It's in a project asking to find the min of that function f(x) without giving details about it except the range of value of x and $\mu$. I was bagging my head for a while trying to understand why that formula? what it stands for? :(

Comment: If $C$ was the *reciprocal* of the covariance the result would simply be the squared [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). It's probably a typo.

Comment: @Emre: +1. Thank you very much. C was given as a positive semidefinite matrix with a hint of covariance matrix. So you're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the random vector $\vec{X}=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)^T$ and its mean vector $\mathbb{E}[\vec{X}]=\vec{\mu}=(\mu_1,\mu_2,...,\mu_n)^T$. Also, consider the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ of $\vec{X}$. The sum that you cite is the result of expanding
$$\left(\vec{X}-\vec{\mu}\right)^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\left(\vec{X}-\vec{\mu}\right)\text{.}$$
I really can't see the meaning of this result, but it resembles the squared [Mahalanobis Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) a lot, although as you described the elements of the sum, it doesn't quite fit the description. In the case of the squared Mahalanobis Distance, which is defined as
$$\left(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}\right)^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\left(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}\right)\text{,}$$
we now consider $\vec{x}$ as another random vector (where not necessarily $\mathbb{E}[\vec{x}]=\vec{\mu}$). If you interpret this as samples, the result (a number) is a form of a generalized distance between $\vec{x}$ and the distribution defined by a mean vector $\vec{\mu}$ and a covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. In other words, the distance where you actually weigh for the second order information of the distribution (i.e. for the covariance matrix).

Comment: This is great. The original question only gives C as a positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix, but also mentions covariance matrix as an example of it. Since, inverse of an PSD matrix is also an PSD matrix, it seems to be very close to Mahalanobis. And I guess the min of that sum could be interpreted as the closest possible distance of test point to a set of sample points, right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that's seems like a very good interpretation :-).

Comment: So if we add the condition $i \neq j$ which mean all the diagonal elements of the matrix are not taken into account, does this interpretation still hold? What do you think? (Please see my edited question)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a typo; C should be the reciprocal of the covariance. The resulting function is called the squared [Mahalonobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), and it occurs naturally wherever Gaussian distributions are involved, being the argument of the exponential term of the [multivariate normal density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).

Comment: +1 @Emre: Thanks again for your response. Please see my edited version of the question. Do you have any comment on what the summation could be with the condition $i \neq j$?. Many thanks.

Comment: Now you subtracted the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29), which is the norm, normalized by the variance of each term. Can you show us the source? It is incumbent on the writer to explain the notation, not the reader to guess it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, Emre. Unfortunately, the source is not available online. I have only the hard copy which is a piece of paper with the formula.